# the question is that i need to find the sum of odd numbers in Fibonacci series , but i need the last element to be <400000

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def calculateSum(n):

    fibo =[0] * (n+1) 
    fibo[1] = 1
    sm = fibo[0] + fibo[1]                                  
    for i in range(2,n+1):
         fibo[i] = fibo[i-1] + fibo[i-2]
         if fibo[i]%2!=0:
          sm = sm + fibo[i]
    return sm
```

I wrote this code but didn't know how to make it calculate to the `element < 400000`

Comment: What's `organ`?

Comment: Do you mean O(n) time? what is `organ`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this line,

```
if fibo[i]%2!=0:
```

to,

```
if fibo[i]%2!=0 and fibo[i] < 400000:
```

This is checking if the element is indivisible by 2 and is less than 400000.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a for loop use a while loop and set the termination condition to something like example: while sum < 40000.